# appengine cannot connect to google cloud sql with non ROOT user

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have created a user in Google Cloud SQL. When i use a 3rd party mysql admin tool, i can connect using a non root account. However, in my app engine account, i can't do it. i'm not sure why. I tried the following connection strings:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(unix_socket='/cloudsql/' + SQL_INSTANCE, user='username', db='dbname')
db = MySQLdb.connect(host='x.x.x.x', port=3306, user='username', passwd="passwd")
```

None of which works.

Comment: What error do you get? Can you also check that using 'SHOW GRANTS FOR username@localhost' to see the permissions are correct.

Comment: from app engine, i'm getting:
 
    `super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
OperationalError: (1044, &quot;Access denied for user 'mtogether'@'localhost' to database '*******'&quot;)`


the show grants command is reporting `GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*----------------'`

Answer (score 2):

The `SHOW GRANTS` should indicate that your user has access to that table. The USAGE permission is not sufficient to use a particular database.

I was able to properly connect using a particular user and password. The `MySQLdb.connect` I used was like this:

```
  db = MySQLdb.connect(
      unix_socket='/cloudsql/XXXXXXX',
      user='test', passwd='test')
```

I added the user like this:

```
mysql> GRANT ALL ON `%`.* TO test@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'test';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.19 sec)
```

How the grants look like:

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR test@localhost;
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for test@localhost                                                                                   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'test'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*94BDCEBE19083CE2A1F959FD02F964C7AF4CFC29' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `%`.* TO 'test'@'localhost'                                                         |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.11 sec)

mysql>
```

I hope this helps.